# Geolocation in webview error

Tags: android, android-emulator, geolocation

On an Android 2.2 emulator, loading a blank page with the following script fails:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          function(pos){
            var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
            var lon= pos.coords.longitude;
            alert('success ' + lat + ',' + lon);
          },
          function(){
              alert('geoloc test FAILED');
          }
        );
```

Specifically, it causes the error:

```
I/Database(  306): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
```

I've added pretty much every geo-related permission I can find to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

I'm not sure what else I can do!  I've been at this for hours with no progress - any insight would be greatly appreciated.

(I am able to view my location in the emulator browser after sending `geo fix`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**According to [the phonegap mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/7247160db72252ad), this error is normal and can be safely ignored.**  All Android devices 2.X onwards have geolocation built into the browser.

A possibly helpful note:  when testing geolocation, it helped me a lot to use [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html) to set a fake location, or simply telnet to localhost:5554 and run the command `geo fix 50.0 50.0`, for example, to set mock gps lat/long coords to (50, 50).